# Getter and Setter for member variable in Python

Tags: python

I know that it is not recommended to write getter and setter for class member variables in Python. Still I need to do it because I have a complex object which internally contains a lot of objects in depth. I need to expose a property/function in container object that will get and/or set member of inner object. How can I do this in Python?

```
def responseoperationcode(self,operationcode=None):
    if operationcode:
        self.innerobject.operationcode=operationcode
    else:
        return self.innerobject.operationcode
```

Above given function can act as a getter and setter but the syntax to use it would be confusing. My requirement is that user should get its value without using parenthesis and to set values he should pass parameters. Something like this

```
objectname.responseoperationcode ##this should return the value
```

and

```
objectname.responseoperationcode("SUCCESS")##this should set the value
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you check `property`? http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Comment: Side note: when you test for `None`, use `if operationcode is not None:`.

Comment: Having it work exactly like you want is impossible, because `objectname.responseoperationcode("SUCCESS")` is indistinguishable from `(objectname.responseoperationcode)("SUCCESS")` for Python. That is, if your value is returned without calling anything, then calling the same thing will just call the returned value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python supports [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). You can change your code to:

```
@property
def responseoperationcode(self):
    return self.innerobject.operationcode

@responseoperationcode.setter    
def responseoperationcode(self, value):    
    self.innerobject.operationcode = value
```

Now you can use the `responseoperationcode` function like a field, e.g.:

```
objectname.responseoperationcode # this returns the value
objectname.responseoperationcode = "SUCCESS" # this sets the value
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have access to the definition of the inner objects, you could write a getter method there. Then whole thing would look similar to this:

```
class OuterObject:
    innerObject        

    def getInnerField(self, field=None):
        if field == None: 
            return self.innerObject.getField()
        else:
            self.innerObject.setField(field)



class InnerObject:
    field

    def getField(self):
        return self.field

    def setField(self, field):
        self.field = field
```